# regexp for phone (555) 555-9087

Tags: regex, html

I'm using the pattern attribute for my `<input type="tel" />` and I'm having a hard time with the regexp. I tried pattern=`"d{10]"` and pattern=`"d{3}[\)]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}"` but it does not work.

Comment: 'does not work'... what exactly are you trying to do? detect a phone number? extract number components (area code, exchange, ....)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
pattern="\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}"
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMaXA/
Try messing with the value in the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> str='(777) 777-9087'
>>> r=re.search('\(([^\)]+)\)\s*(\d+-\d+)',str)
>>> r.groups()
('777', '777-9087')
```